# Monitoring Byte Usage of Large MySQL InnoDB Buffer Pools?

Tags: mysql, performance-monitoring, innodb, telegraf, mysql5.7

I am trying to monitor the total number of used bytes in a MySQL 5.7 InnoDB Buffer Pool, that can go up to 100GB, using `Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data` but it seems that this status variable is a 32-bit unsigned integer when I query it, so it overflows when bytes go past 2^32.

It seems to be an unsigned long integer internally in MySQL (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/storage/innobase/include/srv0srv.h#L892)?

At first I thought the overflow was in was my monitoring stack (Telegraf+InfluxDB+Grafana)-

[Grafana Graph showing Interger Overflow over time with Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data being 490MB currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxOwW.jpg)

-but querying MySQL directly seems to reveal it's from MySQL and not in my monitoring solution:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE Variable_name = "Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data"
```

-yields `490371968` for roughly the same sample timestamp seen in Grafana above.

How can I accurately monitor the true value?

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'`
107374182400

Comment: Perhaps you have a 32-bit compilation of either MySQL or the OS or Grafana?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: What is the value of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';`?  Perhaps it is about 500M ?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version_compile_os'`  
version_compile_os is Win64  
  
`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'`
innodb_buffer_pool_size is 107374182400 bytes (~107GB)  
Server has 130GB of RAM.  
  
Server was not restarted at that timestamp. No mention of restarts in MySQL logfile.
Using grafana-8.1.5.windows-amd64. Even if Grafana was 32-bit even querying for `Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data` directly with a MySQL client reveals the problem, meaning it can't be Grafana.
@Rick James

Comment: Manually monitor `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data';` to get some more insight into what is happening.  (I guess I don't know the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

That graph looks like MySQL restarted (or the server restarted) at about 12:16.  The buffer_pool will grow until it hits `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

If you don't have enough RAM, for the buffer_pool (plus other stuff), then it can crash.  That setting should be set to about 70% of available RAM.

Comment: Server was not restarted at that timestamp. No mention of restarts in MySQL logfile. See my other comments on the Question.